# Is global module required as dependency in jboss-deployment-structure.xml?

Tags: jboss

My scenario:

I have defined module as global module in *standalone.xml*

Do I need to add this module as dependency in j*boss-deployment-structure.xml*?

Answer (score 0):

No.

See the [wildfly ee subsystem documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Subsystem+configuration):

> Global modules is a set of JBoss Modules that will be added as dependencies to the JBoss Module of every Java EE deployment. Such dependencies allows Java EE deployments to see the classes exported by the global modules.